# Classification of quadratic submodules in $\mathbb C[[t]]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbb C[[t]]$ be the ring of formal series with complex coefficients. Let $M$ be a finite rank free module over this ring. Let $Q$ be a regular quadratic form
on $M$. (E.g., the standard quadratic form $\sum x_i^2$.)

Is there a classification of submodules of $M$, that is, of the orbits of the action of $SO(Q)$ on the submodules? I am ready to assume that the submodule $N$ is such that $M/N$ is torsion free, but I don't want to assume that $N/(t)$ is non-degenerate as a quadratic space.

Comment: title: you mean submodules, not submodulies?